# Update title in edit suggestions page to reflect the number of edits available to be reviewed

Tags: feature-request, review

I propose we update the title in the edit suggestions review page to reflect the number of edits available to be reviewed. Similar functionality is already implemented in pages involved in viewing new questions, as shown below:

[image: chrome tab showing (13) in page title]

I find this extremely useful as it allows me to monitor the activity on a page while in another tab. For the same reason, I believe having this functionality implemented on the edit suggestions page would benefit the community.

The same design could be used, with the number of suggested edits available to be reviewed wrapped in parentheses, as in:

[image: chrome tab showing (3) in page title for suggested edits page]

The clickable gray box could also be replicated, as in:

[image: 13 questions with new activity]

Could be replaced with the slightly modified:

[image: e3 new edit suggestions available for review]

Comment: The number of edit suggestions available is very.. dynamic and changes every second - will probably be too much load on the server to support such a thing.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Well, it doesn't have to be exact. I think if it updated every 5 or 10 seconds it would be accurate enough to be useful.